# Apache, Ubuntu, SSL, alias and virtual

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl

First let me state that I am a Linux noob. I am learning as I go here. Here is my situation. I have an Ubuntu 16lts server, with apache. The software we just installed comes with "samples" These samples are stored in the same directory structure as the program. The instructions have you add an alias and a directory to the apache2 config file. Like so

Alias /pccis_sample /usr/share/prizm/Samples/php

This actually worked :)

However now we want to make sure this site is SSL. I did manage to use openssl to import to Ubuntu the certificates we wanted to use. (i am open to using self signed though at this point its non prod so i dont care) 
In trying to find out the right way to tell Apache i want to use SSL for this directory and which cert i want to use. Things went wonky on me. I did manage to get it to use ssl but with browser warning as one would epexct with a self signed cert. I had thought that i could just install the cert on our devs machines and that would go away. But no dice. Now in trying to fix all that i just done broke it. SOOOO What I am looking for is not neccessarily and spoon fed answer but rather any good tools, scripts, articles tips tricks gotchas that i can use to get this sucker done.

Thanks

Comment: Once you get to more than localhost, self signed certs are a pain to manage.  Instead, manage a self-created CA and sign your dev certs wtih that.  As many certs as you want at any time, only one "set up on each client".  https://deliciousbrains.com/ssl-certificate-authority-for-local-https-development/

Comment: Thank you sir! i will give this a go. Does the Alias usage in Apache have any affect on how I need to enable SSL configure ssl for Apache once i have that cert?

Comment: I'll whip up an answer for you

Answer (score 0):

You need to import your certificate(s) into the browsers trusted store.  For each browser on each machine you test with.  "What a pain!" you probably think.  You are right.

Make it less painful - go through it once.  Create your own Certificate Authority, and add *that* to your browsers trusted certificates/issuers listing.  This way, you modify each one once, but then any certificate created by your CA certificate's key will be considered valid by those clients.

https://deliciousbrains.com/ssl-certificate-authority-for-local-https-development/

Note that when configuring Apache or other services, they will still need an issued/signed certificate that corresponds correctly to the hostname that is being used to address them.

Words of warning - consider these to be big, red, bold, and blinking.

DO NOT take the lazy way and do a wildcard, etc. DO keep your key and passphrase under strict control.  Remember - your clients will implicitly trust any certificate signed by this key, so it is possible for someone to use the key and create certificates for other domains and effectively MITM the clients.